# MVC Redirection to another page result error 404 resource not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I am trying to redirect to another page resulting error 404 unable to solve

My view page `UserDashBoard.cshtml`"having code,

```
<fieldset >
    <legend > User DashBoard </legend>

    @if(Session["UserName"] != null)
    { <text >
    Welcome @Session["UserName"].ToString() </text>
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm("GetSurvey", "DashboardController"))
    {
    <input type="submit" value="Some text" />
    }
</fieldset>
```

I want to redirect to page `GetSurvey.cshtml` with controller `DashboardController.cs`

`GetSurvey` is like,

```
@model List<SelectListItem>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetSurvey";
}

<h2>Survey List</h2>
<fieldset>
    <legend> User DashBoard </legend>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("GetSurvey", "DashboardController", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.DropDownList("ddlCustomers", Model)
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
</fieldset>
```

and `DashboardController` is,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Survey.Controllers
{
    public class DashboardController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Dashboard/

        public ActionResult GetSurvey()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> customerList = Survey();
            return View(customerList);
          //  return View();
        }

        public ActionResult GetSurvey(string ddlCustomers)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> customerList = Survey();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlCustomers))
            {
                SelectListItem selectedItem = customerList.Find(p => p.Value == ddlCustomers);
                ViewBag.Message = "Name: " + selectedItem.Text;
                ViewBag.Message += "\\nID: " + selectedItem.Value;
            }
            return View(customerList);
        }
        private static List<SelectListItem> Survey()
        {
            SurveyAppEntities ObjectSur=new SurveyAppEntities();
            List<SelectListItem> customerList = (from p in ObjectSur.Surveys.AsEnumerable()  
                                                 select new SelectListItem
                                                 {
                                                     Text = p.Title,
                                                     Value = p.ID.ToString()
                                                 }).ToList();

            return customerList;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why it is not redirecting to page mentioned above more over I had same issue when I start project as I rename the `HomeController` name.

ROUTES:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: its your routes, please post your routes

Comment: i have updated post with my routes

Comment: Your forms use `POST`. Your controller only handles `GET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to check what is hapenning in your application.

A few tool exist on the internet for logging HTTP/HTTPS tracffic, one such too is [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), when browsing to a link on your server, you can see what data is being sent and what URL is being requested from your project.
To make it capture local data, you need to go in your project settings, and the specific URL that is presented, just append .fiddler after localhost. 
e.g http://localhost.fiddler:4444/MyTestApp

The above will provide you with more data when debugging your application.

for now, just remove the **Controller** part from **DashboardController** in your view, that should now point to the correct URL, also please not that you need to Decorate your GetSurvey method with [POST] as GET is implied by default, you can override this behavior by using an overload of the @Html.BeginForm method.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("someAction", "someController", FormMethod.Get))
{
    ...
}
```